# GLSL - are texture lookups optimized?

Tags: optimization, opengl, glsl, shader, textures

Let's consider following GLSL examples:

1.

```
uniform sampler2D t;
...
void main() {
   float val_r = texture2D(t, coords).r;
   float val_g = texture2D(t, coords).g;
   float val_b = texture2D(t, coords).b;
   float val_a = texture2D(t, coords).a;
```

2.

```
uniform sampler2D t;
...
void main() {
   vec4 data = texture2D(t, coords);
   float val_r = data.r;
   float val_g = data.g;
   float val_b = data.b;
   float val_a = data.a;
```

3.

```
uniform sampler2D t;
...
void main() {
   vec4 data1 = texture2D(t, coords);
   vec4 data2 = texture2D(t, coords);
   vec4 data3 = texture2D(t, coords);
   vec4 data4 = texture2D(t, coords);
   float val_r = data1.r;
   float val_g = data2.g;
   float val_b = data3.b;
   float val_a = data4.a;
```

Is 2. faster than 1.?
Or are they equal due to obvious compiler optimizations?

What about 3.? Of course this makes no sense, but for the clarity of my shaders code, such redundant texture lookups may occur. I'm wondering if they are optimized / cached somehow or if I should avoid them.

Comment: I guess the usual answer applies here too: It depends on the implementation.

Comment: Of course, but I'm asking about real-word experience. :) There's a chance that somebody was benchmarking it. Practically, if most of modern devices and their drivers support such optimizations, it's sufficient for me.

Comment: PVRUniSCoEditor says that the compiler optimizes it for you, but it would be nice to see why you'd ever do this.

Comment: This is not related to GLSL. It doesn't make sense to write code like 1 at all, in any language. Because what if you want to rename coords variable? Now you must do that in 4 places. Or what if you need to add something to it - again changing code in 4 places.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: please keep your obvious idiocy for yourself. I was testing an idea of optimization of GPGPU calculations (WebGL), which required quite complex fragment shaders. I was trying to make code more readable and maintainable by reorganization of source, but it could cause some redundant texture lookups. Provided examples were the simplest (and synthetic) possible ways of the problem presentation. They do not present my real solutions..

Comment: @NicolBolas - That's a little too harsh. You could have stated this in a way that didn't insult the asker. piotrek meant well by his question.

Answer (score 3):

It is not mentioned in the spec that the GLSL compiler should do any optimizations. This means the better way is to avoid premature pessimization. This code

```
uniform sampler2D t;

void main() {
   vec4 val = texture2D(t, coords);
```

is the best one. No reason to create float variables, because you always can access vector's components directly via `val.x` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, like others said it depends totally on the implementation. But whereas the compiler may be able to optimize those obvious cases, the situation might be totally different for your actual *"real-world"* problem.

> I was trying to make code more readable and maintainable by
>   reorganization of source, but it could cause some redundant texture
>   lookups. Provided examples were the simplest (and synthetic) possible
>   ways of the problem presentation. They do not present my real
>   solutions.

This sounds like your actual code does not really match the examples you presented, because all three of them are completely ridiculous compared to a simple `vec4 val = texture2D(t, coords);` (yes, even the 2nd, like already explained by *Sergey*) and don't add any readability or maintainability.

So I guess in your actual *"real-world"* code you seperate out those texturing calls in much more complicated ways, maybe into different functions, or into conditional branches or maybe just separate them by a whole lot of other instructions. And if the compiler can optimize this actual code is a totally different question that needs to be answered for this particular code.

So in the end the only thing you can be certainly sure of is, that example 2 will never be slower than examples 1 and 3. And on the other hand that the optimization behaviour for your 3 examples doesn't tell you anything practically, because that is surely not your actual *"real-world"* code, which might be arbitrarily more complex to analyse by the optimizer. (And if it is indeed your *"real-world"* code, then your definition of *"real"* doesn't *really* match the *real* definition of *"real"* and *Sergey*'s answer is the only correct one).